# Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition - "An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

It seems that my Visual Studio 2013 C++ Professional Edition is completely broken and I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue or not. What happens is I will create a fresh solution/project (I make sure it has a different name from any I used before). An error message will then always pop up saying "An item with the same key has already been added". From this point forward, whenever I select Properties->General the same error message will come up. The General properties for the project contains no information about the executable, program output or anything. I wonder if the system is even configured to use the correct tool-chain. Any advice or knowledge on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Fair question. A screenshot or two might help. Have you tried reinstalling VS?

Comment: Haven't tried reinstalling yet. I attached some screenshots in case it might help.

Comment: This installation would indeed appear to be completely hosed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a long shot, but are you setting multiple environment variables which differ only by case?

(I have seen a similar error message when using msbuild with cygwin, and I end up with both "temp" and "TEMP" environment variables set).